# GDAL tiling with a lot of MrSID files

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdalwarp, gdal2tiles

I'm trying to generate tiles for a region with a surface of 85k km2. The data source are MrSID files (2734 files). I'm using gdal to achieve this task.

It works fine with a small subset of MrSID, but with all the source files it would take more years than I could live :).

My process for generating tiles is the following:

```
# create the mosaic
gdalwarp -of GTiff -dstalpha -r cubic [MrSID Files] mosaic.tiff`

# generate tiles from mosaic
gdal2tiles.py -r cubic -s EPSG:23030 -z 3-17 -v mosaic.tiff
```

At first I've chosen a subset of 30 MrSID and it takes 10 hours and it works. Check [here](http://www.erosion.geographica.gs/tileado/openlayers.html).

After that, I've tried with all the MrSID files and I can't reach to create the mosaic, after two days gdalwarp is at 1% processing the first MrSID.

As a workaround, I've tried to avoid the creation of the big mosaic, I've called gdal2tiles for each MrSID, and merging the shared tiles with imagemagic. The issue with this method is that I need a huge quantity of temporal files (30 MrSID files (90MB) give me around 30GB of temporal files).

Any ideas how can achieve this? Is it possible create such a big mosaic? Do you suggest me another strategy?

MrSID files are like this:

```
Driver: MrSID/Multi-resolution Seamless Image Database (MrSID)
Files: test/807-1-3.sid
Size is 7355, 4796
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (309892.000000000000000,4291525.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  ICC__Profile=0,0,1,148,65,68,66,69,2,16,0,0,109,110,116,114,71,82,65,89,88,89,90,32,0,8,7,212,0,19,0,2,0,29,0,23,97,99,115,112,77,83,70,84,0,0,0,0,110,111,110,101,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,246,214,0,1,0,0,0,0,211,45,65,68,66,69,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,99,112,114,116,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,36,100,101,115,99,0,0,0,228,0,0,0,119,119,116,112,116,0,0,1,92,0,0,0,20,98,107,112,116,0,0,1,112,0,0,0,20,107,84,82,67,0,0,1,132,0,0,0,14,116,101,120,116,0,0,0,0,40,99,41,32,50,48,48,52,32,65,100,111,98,101,32,83,121,115,116,101,109,115,32,73,110,99,46,0,100,101,115,99,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,69,115,99,97,108,97,32,100,101,32,103,114,105,115,101,115,32,45,32,71,97,109,97,32,50,46,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88,89,90,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,243,81,0,1,0,0,0,1,22,204,88,89,90,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,99,117,114,118,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,51,0,0
  IMAGE__COMPRESSION_BLOCK_SIZE=512
  IMAGE__COMPRESSION_GAMMA=2.000000
  IMAGE__COMPRESSION_NLEV=8
  IMAGE__COMPRESSION_VERSION=2,0,0
  IMAGE__COMPRESSION_WEIGHT=4.000000
  IMAGE__CREATION_DATE=Sat Jan 12 13:20:09 2002

  IMAGE__INPUT_FILE_SIZE=35277072.000000
  IMAGE__INPUT_FORMAT=TIFF w/ World File
  IMAGE__INPUT_NAME=H:\Imagenes\MrSid\Vuelo_Americano\comp\807_1_3.TIF
  IMAGE__STATISTICS_MAX=255
  IMAGE__STATISTICS_MEAN=231.585752
  IMAGE__STATISTICS_MIN=1
  IMAGE__STATISTICS_STANDARD_DEVIATION=58.039863
  IMAGE__TARGET_COMPRESSION_RATIO=10.000000
  PShop__ImageResources=
  VERSION=MG2
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  309892.000, 4291525.000) 
Lower Left  (  309892.000, 4286729.000) 
Upper Right (  317247.000, 4291525.000) 
Lower Right (  317247.000, 4286729.000) 
Center      (  313569.500, 4289127.000) 
Band 1 Block=1024x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=3.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=232.406, StdDev=53.985
  Overviews: 3678x2398, 1839x1199, 920x600, 460x300, 230x150, 115x75, 58x38, 29x19
```

Comment: Just curious, any chance you have tif's for the same area?

Comment: No, but I can convert all my MrSID to Tiff. Do you know how to improve this process using Tiffs?

Comment: This may or may not help you. I had some sets of data that consisted of 1-3 large sids and multiple tif's (550+) for the same area. The area is a county in NC. I serve my images from geoserver. To build my cache of tiles from mr sid's was very time consuming, and at that time I did not know of another way to do it. Since then I have learned to use gdal_retile to build a image_pyramid. That whole process is much faster and the quality of my rasters is better. Let me know if you want more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid huge temporary files, you can use [`VRT`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) as format of the mosaic file, whose main advantage is that it's *just an XML file that will be created immediately*:

```
:: create the mosaic (optionally setting the target extent and resolution)
gdalbuildvrt [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] mosaic.vrt *.sid

:: generate tiles from mosaic
gdal2tiles.py -r cubic -s EPSG:23030 -z 3-17 -v mosaic.vrt
```

In order to improve the time performance of the above workflow, I suggest to use a less expensive resampling method or, alternatively, to reduce the number of zoom levels to render in `gdal2tiles.py`.

Comment: Sorry I din't made it clear. The huge temporal files issue is related to the output of gdal2tiles, i.e, I launch gdal2tiles over each MrSID, after that I've an script which analize all the outputs of gdal2tiles (an output folder for each MrSID) and build a unique output merging shared images with imagemagick (composite command).

Comment: I see your point! I cannot use gdalwarp with more than one sources, I've to use gdalbuildvrt. Thanks a lot! It looks like the mosaic vrt is created, let's see how much time takes it tiling...